# Rendering any latex in Inkscape does not work anymore

Tags: inkscape, ghostscript

**The issue is being discussed on Inkscape's repository here:**
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/issues/73

Since I last upgraded Inkscape 0.92.4 (45b59e7, 2019-03-20), and probably its dependencies (I upgrade everything through apt-get), I cannot render latex anymore.

Indeed, on a new file, using Extensions > Render > LaTeX gives the following error:

```
Error: /undefined in .makeoperator

Operand stack:

   false   rectfill   rectfill   --nostringval--

Execution stack:

   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2043   1   3   %oparray_pop   2024   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--

Dictionary stack:

   --dict:1234/1684(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:218/300(L)--   --dict:1234/1684(G)--

Current allocation mode is global

Current file position is 14859

GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

PostScript/PDF Interpreter finished. Return status 256 executed command : gs -q -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dNODISPLAY -dNOEPS "/tmp/psinpIcqFd"

The interpreter seems to have failed, cannot proceed !

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eqtexsvg.py", line 160, in <module>
    e.affect()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 283, in affect
    self.effect()
  File "eqtexsvg.py", line 154, in effect
    svg_open(self, svg_file)
  File "eqtexsvg.py", line 81, in svg_open
    doc = inkex.etree.parse(filename)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1840, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1866, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1770, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1163, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "/tmp/inkscape-UjDLa0/eq.svg", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

The Ghostscript version is GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20).

**WORKAROUND**

There is an extension called [TexText](https://github.com/textext/textext/) that supports `pdf2svg` as explained in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034894/render-latex-is-not-working-in-inkscape-after-installing-to-18-04).

Hence I was able to use LaTeX in Inkscape using the extension. I removed some package to get rid of some message that cluttered my workflow as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490871/lubuntu-g-is-dbus-connection).

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem. Ended up installing the 9.25 version of Ghospscript and it works now.

Comment: How did you revert from ghostscript 9.26 to ghostscript 9.25 cleanly ?

Comment: I am working from a windows machine. I uninstall gs 9.27 (which is what I had), through the usual control panel menu. Then I got the gs 9.25 installation files from here: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/ . After installing the old version, I changed the path variable to the new gs version. After that, it worked smoothly. Hope it works!